# scale_x_date on other column or using hour as well as date

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I have a data frame where I've added the hour onto the end of my date

Data:

```
 structure(list(date = c("2016-01-30 11", "2016-01-30 13", "2016-01-30 16", 
    "2016-01-30 18", "2016-01-30 21", "2016-01-31 2", "2016-01-31 5", 
    "2016-01-31 7", "2016-01-31 13", "2016-01-31 13"), Obs = c(9L, 
    15L, 15L, 16L, 15L, 16L, 15L, 16L, 14L, 9L), score = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "1.5", "2"
    ), class = "factor"), date2_1 = c("2016-01-30", "2016-01-30", 
    "2016-01-30", "2016-01-30", "2016-01-30", "2016-01-31", "2016-01-31", 
    "2016-01-31", "2016-01-31", "2016-01-31"), date2_2 = c(11L, 13L, 
    16L, 18L, 21L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 13L, 13L)), .Names = c("date", "Obs", 
    "score", "date2_1", "date2_2"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000001f0788>)
```

My plot is:

```
ggplot(data = tt, aes(date2_1, Obs, colour=score)) + 
       geom_point() +   
       scale_colour_discrete(drop=TRUE, limits = levels(t$score))
```

In another data frame I only have date (which is equiv to date2_1 in this data) and change the class with `as.Date` such that the following works:

```
ggplot(data = t, aes(date, Obs, colour=score)) + 
       geom_point() + 
       scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels="%d") +  
       scale_colour_discrete(drop=TRUE, limits = levels(t$score))
```

I would like to use `scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels="%d")` on the first plot I've shown, but have the scale using `date2_1` instead of `date`.

Extra: Even better would be using the scale to run from `date` in my sample data, however this isn't of class date as I pasted the hour onto it. This data frame is a subset of another where I do have a datetime column with values like `2016-01-30 11:50:52` which are `POSIXct` if that helps - in fact I use `cSplit` and then paste from that to get my date in the sample data. Using`as.POSIXct` or `strptime` I wasn't able to create a date with just the hour, or if I did `scale_x_date` wouldnt work with it.

Essentially I have a plot with just the date that scales the well, but when using date and hour the datetime is uniformly distributed across the x-axis without taking the date and hour into consideration.

Answers to both options would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear what the problem you are encountering is, nor what is it that you want, but hopefully this can at least point you in the right direction.

The first option you ask is to use the day in `date2_1` in the x axis, I don't see any problem transforming `date2_1` to `Date`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(as.Date(date2_1), Obs, color = score)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date('Date',
               date_breaks = 'day',
               date_labels = '%d')
```

[image]

The second option take the hour in the `date` column into account, so we have to transform it to a `POSIXct`, with the right format (note the use of `scale_x_datetime` instead of `scale_x_date`):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, Obs, color = score)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_datetime('Date',
                   date_breaks = '6 hours',
                   date_labels = '%d h:%H')
```

[image]

Data:

```r
df <- structure(list(date = c("2016-01-30 11", "2016-01-30 13", "2016-01-30 16", 
                              "2016-01-30 18", "2016-01-30 21", "2016-01-31 2", "2016-01-31 5", 
                              "2016-01-31 7", "2016-01-31 13", "2016-01-31 13"), Obs = c(9L, 
                                                                                         15L, 15L, 16L, 15L, 16L, 15L, 16L, 14L, 9L), score = structure(c(3L, 
                                                                                                                                                          1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "1.5", "2"
                                                                                                                                                          ), class = "factor"), date2_1 = c("2016-01-30", "2016-01-30", 
                                                                                                                                                                                            "2016-01-30", "2016-01-30", "2016-01-30", "2016-01-31", "2016-01-31", 
                                                                                                                                                                                            "2016-01-31", "2016-01-31", "2016-01-31"), date2_2 = c(11L, 13L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   16L, 18L, 21L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 13L, 13L)), .Names = c("date", "Obs", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "score", "date2_1", "date2_2"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

(Note that I had to remove `.internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000001f0788>` from your `dput`)

Comment: No idea why I didnt see scale_x_datetime before. TY